# Repair Presentation Error with chart.replace_data()

Tags: python-pptx

I used  the chart.replace_data() to replace the old category labels with the new ones.  When I opened the output presentation, I saw the message to repair the presentation and when I clicked the repair button, all the data of the presentation are gone. Here's my code:

```
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx import Presentation
#from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from google_trans_new import google_translator
trans=google_translator()
proj1 = Presentation("C:/Users/naych/Documents/chart.pptx")

rev_lbl=[]

for slide in proj1.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_chart:
            chart=shape.chart
            if chart.chart_title.has_text_frame:
                chart_title_str=chart.chart_title.text_frame.text
                rev=trans.translate(chart_title_str,lang_tgt='ja')
                chart.chart_title.text_frame.text=rev
             
            print(shape.name)
            chart_data=ChartData()
            for category in chart.plots[0].categories:
                cat_lbl=category.label
                rev_lbl.append(trans.translate(cat_lbl,lang_tgt='ja'))
            chart_data.categories=rev_lbl
             
chart.replace_data(chart_data)
            
proj1.save('chart_lang.pptx')
```

I am very happy if you help me to fix it. Please! Thank you.

Comment: You have to set _all_ of the chart-data, not just the categories. When you call `ChartData()`, you are getting back an _empty_ `ChartData` object. In particular, you also need to set the series and their values with `.add_series()` calls.

Comment: Thank you so much @scanny. It really works.